# how to get the category to display all products in wp e-commerce

Tags: php, wordpress

I have here the code but how can I set it with a specific category

like "Electronic" which has an id of "1"

here is the code

```
<?php 
// get the product categories
$product_categories = wp_get_object_terms( wpsc_the_product_id(), 'wpsc_product_category', array('fields' => 'ids') );
// arguments
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'wpsc-product',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'orderby' => 'rand',
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'wpsc_product_category',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $product_categories
    )
)
);
$related_products = new WP_Query( $args );
// loop over query
if ($related_products->have_posts()) :
echo '<ul>';
while ( $related_products->have_posts() ) : $related_products->the_post();
?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php
endwhile;
echo '</ul>';
endif;
// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

it displays the products on that page, I need to display products based on what category I put in so that it will be different from the page products

Comment: May this help : http://www.subharanjan.in/category-wise-products-display-in-wp-e-commerce/

Answer (score 0):

Select posts only from that category, with a code like this one in the Loop:

```
query_posts(array('category_name' => 'Electronic', 'showposts' => '1'));
if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post();
...
```

**UPDATED**
Example:

```
<?php
query_posts( array( 'category_name' => 'Electronic',
                    'showposts'     => '1' ) );  // Replace '1' with posts quantity per page
echo '<ul>';
if ( have_posts() ): while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
  ?>

<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

<?php
endwhile;
  echo '</ul>';
endif;
// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

I think the last code can replace the script of the question. Not sure, though, because  can't test it.

Note: Of course you would have to create the category and assign posts to that category, or use the existing category: **wpsc_product_category**.